# Should there be a comma before "which meant that" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

According to Grammarly's [blog](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-which/), you should use a comma with non-restrictive phrases:

> Jeff’s new car, **which is less than a month old**, already started
>   leaking oil.

And leave it out with prepositional phrases:

> The platform on **which we built our program is very stable**.

Here's my confusion:

> He forgot the present he had bought for Mary, **which meant that he had to go back home a second time.**

I have no idea what the bolded past is. A non-restrictive phrase? A prepositional phrase? Should there be a comma before it?

Comment: It *could* be turned into a restrictive clause, by removing the comma and replacing *which* with *that* (mostly in US English), but it would be a little strange. It would mean it was a present that, by its very nature rather than something accidental, *made* him go back home. One present was big, another present was small, one was red, and this one made him return home. In a fantasy world it would have a *you must return home* spell on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He forgot the present he had bought for Mary, which meant that he had to go back home a second time.

In this sentence "which meant that he had to go back home a second time" is a **non-restrictive relative clause**, and its **antecedent** is the entire preceding clause "He forgot the present he had bought for Mary." The *which* refers to what is described by the preceding clause, the situation that "He forgot the present he had bought for Mary." And yes, non-restrictive clauses are usually set off by commas.